How can I automatically select and download rows as CSV based on checkbox states and then modify checkbox states after download?

I have a Google Sheet with 20 columns.
Columns C and D contain checkboxes that indicate the  states of two separate row status':

checkboxes in C are for READY status.
checkboxes in D are for EXPORTED status.


Every week, rows are added to the sheet marked READY but not marked EXPORTED.
Periodically, I manually download any rows marked  READY but not EXPORTED and once completed  I update those rows to be marked EXPORTED.

I'm trying to automate this workflow so I can trigger the download as CSV for those rows marked READY but not EXPORTED then have the rows automatically updated to include EXPORTED.
Is there a way to implement this automation in Google Sheets?

RIght now the question is too broad. You are asking "Can I?" but the implications are that you are really  asking that soneone provide you a solutuon/script and are providing a list of features .  If you want help with a script you will need to provide a sample you are working on with details as to where you are stuck. Any error messages and also some sample data before the script runs, and another showing your desired result.

ŠüR0 will you be manually setting the filename and location each time or should the entire process be automated and where will the file be saved?  Is the pain point merely the updating of the selecting of the rows and the updating of the checkboxes?

I prefer the process to be automated and the download to be one single CSV appended with the date in the file name. The pain point is downloading a subset of the rows based on column conditions, followed by changes to the columns themselves so those rows are not downloaded the next time.

I will try to add more info in my answer later when I have time and probably tweak the code.  Thought it was worth getting a proof of concept up for you to flag any misconceptions I didn't feel comfortable not saving the CSV to drive in addition to making it available to download.

Thank you Blindspots. I will try this script out and provide feedback. I think one aspect can be updated that the Google Sheet has several worksheets and I’d like the exported CSV to still be one file while containing rows from all the Worksheets that meet the criteria.

This script saves a copy of the CSV in the drive folder of your choice and logs the download link and the parent folder link.
It uses Google's API to convert to CSV instead of doing it from the sheet values to avoid dealing with issues related to special characters in values (eg. comma's, quotation marks, etc.).
It can be extended to return a clickable URL in the Spreadsheet UI and also to remove old CSV's if that's desirable.
It is currently a container-bound script and the Drive V2 API must be added to your script under Services:


const sheetName = "Sheet1"
const folderId = "3hBopZbR8KxJTyuiW7_363432sx4sUbtP";  // Destination folder Id
const hasHeadingRow = 1;  // 1 or 0; For column labels 

function exportRowsToCSV() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssName = ss.getName();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const csvName = ssName + "_" + sheetName + datestamp() + ".csv";    
  const rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  const cols =  sheet.getMaxColumns();
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, cols);
  const oldFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  // get  values
  const values = range.getValues();
  const hd = Number(hasHeadingRow);

  // store rows to download and skip in arrays
  const download = [], skip = []; 
  values.forEach(function(r,i) {
    let hRow = (hd > 0) && (i < hd);
    let bool = (r[2] === true) && (r[3] === false);  
    ((hRow || bool) && download.push(i+1)) || skip.push(i+1);
  });

  if (download.length > hd) {
    
    // Batch rows  into ranges to reduce API calls
    function batchRows(rowArr) {
      let batch = rowArr.reduce((rng, i) => {
        const r = rng[rng.length - 1];
        if (r && i === r[1] + 1) {
          r[1] = i;
          return rng;
        }
        rng.push([i, i]);
        return rng;
      }, []);
      return batch;
    }

    // make copy of spreadsheet 
    const newFile = oldFile.makeCopy(csvName, folder);
    
    // Update checkboxes in original
    batchRows(download).forEach(([beg, end]) => sheet.getRange(beg,4,end-beg+1).check());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    const newID = newFile.getId();
    const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newID).getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // delete skipped rows from copy prior to CSV conversion
    batchRows(skip).reverse().forEach(([beg, end]) => newSheet.deleteRows(beg, end-beg+1));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    // Create CSV from copy
    const path = ["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/", "/export?format=csv"]; 
    const exported = UrlFetchApp.fetch(path.join(newID), {
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),},
    });
    const csvFile = Drive.Files.insert(
      { title: csvName, 
        mimeType: "application/vnd.csv", 
        parents: [{id: folderId}] }, exported.getBlob());
    const downloadLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+ csvFile.getId();
    const folderLink = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" + folderId;
    Drive.Files.remove(newID);  // remove duplicated spreadsheet
    
    console.log("Download Link:\n" + downloadLink + "\n\nDrive Folder Link:\n" + folderLink);
  } else {
    console.log("Nothing to export") 
  }
}

function datestamp(d) {
  !d && (d = new Date(Date.now())); 
  let bits = [[d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()],
              [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()]];
  bits.forEach(function(val,i) {
    let tmp = [];
    val.forEach(v => tmp.push(v.toString().padStart(2,0)));
    bits.splice(i, 1, tmp.join(i?'.':'-'));
  })
  return '_' + bits.join('_');
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addMenu(
    // "⚙️ Export Rows to CSV",
    "⚙️ Export Rows to CSV",
    [{ name: "Export rows marked 'Ready' & Not 'Exported')",
       functionName: "exportRowsToCSV" }]
  );
}

